# System of linearly coupled ODE with quadratic term

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I am looking forward to solve the system of equations 
$$\frac{d x_i}{d t}=a_ix_i^2+b_ix_i-\sum\limits_{j\neq i}^nb_jx_j-d_i,$$
with $x_i\geq 0$, $a_i,b_i,c_i,d_i>0$ and $i\in[1,n]$.

Without the linear coupling term, the system reduces to a set of independent Riccati equations with constant coefficients that can be solved.

With the coupling, the system looks like a matrix equation but I don't know how to represent the quadratic term in matrix form.

Any kind of help for finding the solution, or link to literature would be very helpful.

Thank you!

Comment: You can always write $\boldsymbol{\dot{x}} = \boldsymbol{g}(\boldsymbol{x}) + \boldsymbol{\underline{B}} \boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{d}$, where $g_i(\boldsymbol{x}) = a_i x_i^2$, $i=1,2,\dots,n$.

Comment: Dear Christoph, 
Thank you for your reply!
Although I am not sure I understand how to use your proposition to solve my system.

Supose that $B$ is diagonalizable so $B=V\lambda V^{-1}$.
Then system becomes

$\dot{x}=g(x)+V\lambda V^{-1}x−d$ 

then left multiplying both sides by $V^{-1}$ I obtain 
 
$V^{-1}\dot{x}=V^{-1}g(x)+\lambda V^{-1}x−V^{-1}d$

which is  solving the system of independent equations

$\dot{x_i'}=g_i'(x)+\lambda_i' x_i'−d_i'$

with $\dot{x'}=V^{-1}\dot{x}$, $\lambda'=V^{-1}\lambda$, $g'(x)=V^{-1}g(x)$ and $d'=V^{-1}d$.

Am I correct  ?
Best regards

Comment: Yes, I think it doesn't help much for the solution, it's just a way to write the system in a more compact form. If you set $x = V x'$ you'll also note that the nonlinearity is no longer diagonal, as now $g_i'(x')$ depends on all of the $x_j'$, $j=1,2,\dots,n$.
I would recommend to go for a numerical solution.